# Is a synchronous method call possible in Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, asynchronous

A Lightning Component - lets call it component B - can define a [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods.htm) (that can have arguments) like this:

```
<aura:method name="doAbc" action="{!c.doAbc}"/>
```

that can be called from another component - lets call it component A - quite simply in the controller or helper JavaScript:

```
cmpB.doAbc();
```

But this is implemented inside the framework via an event:

```
var eventDef = $A.$eventService$.$getEventDef$("aura:methodCall");
```

and so is asynchronous. The JavaScript code immediately after the call can't rely on the side effects of the call and also there is no way such a method call can have a return value.

Is there a simple pattern that can be used to achieve (or simulate) a synchronous call between two components?

Comment: Have you tried promises?

Comment: @Sebastian, I believe promises are used for asynchronous call only.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies

Comment: Read the comments below for an explanation on why that's not the case. They're usually used for async calls, but they don't have to be.

Answer (score 3):

I believe those calls are synchronous. I have code like this:

```
var resultOfB;
cmpB.doAbc( param1, function(returnVal){ 
    resultOfB = returnVal; 
} );

if(resultOfB){ ...}
```

Your method def:

```
<aura:method name="doABC" action="{!c.doNext}" 
  description=""> 
    <aura:attribute name="param" type="Object" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="callback" type="Object" /> 
</aura:method>
```

Comment: Thought passing a callback function was usually necessary when the response is only available later?

Comment: Typically, but in this case, since there is no server trip or setTimeout the code runs straight through.